# How to edit code in the source window using realgud?

Tags: python, debugging, realgud

I've started using realgud:pdb for python debugging in emacs: https://github.com/realgud/realgud

When you begin a realgud session, it opens a command window and a source window.

Keys like 'n' and 'b' typed inside the source window execute pdb commands, like 'next' or 'breakpoint.'

I would like to make modifications to the source code while I debug, but this is impossible if my keystrokes in the source window are captured by the debugging application.

Am I missing something?  What's the right, effective workflow for making changes to source using realgud based on information I learn in the debugging process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `realgud-srcbuf-lock` variable:

> Set source buffers read-only when the debugger is active.
>   A setting of `nil` allows editing, but Short-Key-mode use may inhibit this.

You can also use `C-x C-q` in `realgud-short-key-mode` to turn read-only mode off.

Comment: Thank you. I notice this /only/ turns it off. Ideally, I'd expect to toggle back and forth.  When I press C-x C-q a second time, read-only-mode is back on, but I don't regain my ability to use pdg commands like I did before `C-x C-q`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's back if I go back into the command buffer then return to the source window.  But it does not toggle back simply by staying in the source window.

Comment: Does invoking `M-x realgud-short-key-mode` turn it on?